# Display query results without table line within mysql shell ( nontabular output )

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to display query results like below within mysql shell?

```
mysql> select code, created_at from my_records;
    code         created_at
1213307927  2013-04-26 09:52:10
8400000000  2013-04-29 23:38:48
8311000001  2013-04-29 23:38:48
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

instead of

```
mysql> select code, created_at from my_records;
+------------+---------------------+
|     code   |          created_at |
+------------+---------------------+
| 1213307927 | 2013-04-26 09:52:10 |
| 8400000000 | 2013-04-29 23:38:48 |
| 8311000001 | 2013-04-29 23:38:48 |
+------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The reason I'm asking because I have some tedious task that I need to copy the output and paste it on other tool.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> **--raw, -r**

For tabular output, the “boxing” around columns enables one column value to be distinguished from another. For nontabular output (such as is produced in batch mode or when the --batch or --silent option is given), special characters are escaped in the output so they can be identified easily. Newline, tab, NUL, and backslash are written as \n, \t, \0, and \\. The --raw option disables this character escaping.

The following example demonstrates tabular versus nontabular output and the use of raw mode to disable escaping:

```
% mysql
mysql> SELECT CHAR(92);
+----------+
| CHAR(92) |
+----------+
| \        |
+----------+

% mysql --silent
mysql> SELECT CHAR(92);
CHAR(92)
\\

% mysql --silent --raw
mysql> SELECT CHAR(92);
CHAR(92)
\
```

From [**MySQL Docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_raw)

Comment: And if you're like me and want _just_ the result without column names, include the `--skip-column-names` option as well.

Answer (score 18):

Not exactly what you need, but it might be useful. Add \G at the end of the query

```
select code, created_at from my_records\G;
```

Query result will look like this:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
 code: 1213307927
 created_at: 2013-04-26 09:52:10
*************************** 2. row ***************************
 code: 8400000000  
 created_at: 2013-04-29 23:38:48
```

Comment: is there a way to alphabetically sort the columns in this approach?

Answer (score 11):

## One-liner

```sh
mysql -u YOURUSER -p --password=YOURPASSWORD -s -r -e "show databases;"        
mysql -u root -p --password=abc12345 -s -r -e "show databases;"
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass the `-s` parameter `mysql -s`.

Answer (score 6):

mysql --skip-column-names --silent --raw --execute "select * from somewhere;"

To make these the default options for your user, add the following to ~/.my.cnf
skip_column_names
silent
raw

Answer (score 3):

#### Quick Workaround:

Using the more recent MySQL clients (not sure which versions), you can use the PAGER directive to manipulate the results.  Note that you may have to change the sed expression to avoid clobbering your data.

```
> PAGER sed 's/|//g'
PAGER set to 'sed 's/|//g''
barracuda@db-ess-rw.us-east-2.ess.aws.vt2.com [ess]
> SELECT 'row1_col1' AS column1, 'row1_col2' AS column2
  UNION ALL SELECT 'row2_col1', 'row2_col2';
+---------+---------+
 column1  column2 
+---------+---------+
 row1_col1  row1_col2 
 row2_col1  row2_col2 
+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Beefore you do this, you may want to get the current value of your PAGER:

```
> PAGER
PAGER set to 'less'
```

To reset to using 'less' as the PAGER

```
> PAGER less
PAGER set to 'less'
```

More fun with PAGER:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/01/21/fun-with-the-mysql-pager-command/

Answer (score 1):

I solved this but using concat_ws to join the results together and then add a space (first argument)

```
select concat_ws (' ',ipNetFull,ipUsage,broadcast,gateway) from ipNets;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get MySQL client output without the surrounding table, you can run your query from the linux command line instead of through the mysql client:

```
$ echo "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ','DROP TABLE',TABLE_NAME,';') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%';" | mysql dbname
```

bonus: you can pipe the output through sort and stuff, or even back into mysql:

```
$ echo "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ','DROP TABLE',CONCAT_WS('.',TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME),';') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'i\'m\_not\_that\_mean';" | mysql | mysql;
```

Answer (score -1):

So confused by the question and answers. ran sql and result kept displaying without lines or non tabular format. Later realized there is an option when you right click on the query space, navigate to "results to" > "results to grid". This Should set it back to tabular format.

There is also an option for "results to text" which was the format I was experiencing.

:)!

Comment: You are right, but in this case is about console, and get the results directly and no needing to do anything more, prolly because we need to automate a script. Bests regards bro.